# asp.net dynamically created gridview edit template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I have a gridview to which I dynamically bind data to.
It features SELECT and EDIT commands.

When it is in EDIT mode all the fields turn into textboxes that can be edited.

What I would like to do is add an Ajax Calendar Extender to one of the textboxes.

How can I create a TemplateField just for the one field?
Is it even possible? I know how to do it if I bound all fields and assign the data via a SqlDataSource.

I have tried adding the templatefield to my gridview but the data is just not showing up:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCheckResults" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvCheckResults_RowDataBound"
OnRowEditing="gvCheckResults_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gvCheckResults_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvCheckResults_RowCancelingEdit"
                     OnRowDeleting="gvCheckResults_RowDeleting">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateOfTest" SortExpression="DateOfTest">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfTest") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="test" runat="server"
                                    TargetControlID="TextBox1"
                                    CssClass="calendar"
                                    Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfTest") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

How the data gets bound:

```
protected void TestDataBind()
    {
        string Name = txtCheckName.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            Name = null;
        gvCheckResults.DataSource = dataContext.GetRecords(Name);
        gvCheckResults.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code where you are binding your data source to the grid view? Does the data source you are binding have a public property called `DateOfTest`?

Comment: So in code behind I have a dbml class and a stored procedure that does the SELECT query from the DB. The query is different based on what the user enters in a search textbox. Edit above with extra code